# Refresh marker clusters after GeoJSON layer has changed

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am setting up a GeoJSON layer and on top of it a MarkerCluster layer

```
this.itemLayer = L.geoJson(items, layerOptions)
this.clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup()
this.clusterLayer.addLayer(this.itemLayer)
this.clusterLayer.addTo(this.map)
```

Upon update I am doing:

```
this.itemLayer.clearLayers()
this.itemLayer.addData(newItems)
this.clusterLayer.refreshClusters(this.itemLayer)
```

But the clusters do not appear, nor do the items in the `itemLayer`

## Solution

```
this.itemLayer.clearLayers()
this.itemLayer.addData(this.props.items)
this.clusterLayer.clearLayers()
this.clusterLayer.addLayer(this.itemLayer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet.markercluster does not keep track of Layer Groups (like your `this.itemLayer` GeoJSON layer group) unfortunately. When passed a group to `clusterLayer.addLayer()`, MCG will extract all individual (i.e. non-group) layers from that group, and forget any reference to the group.

See also [Leaflet.markercluster issue #647](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/647#issuecomment-200188598).

Therefore when clearing your group with `this.itemLayer.clearLayers()`, it effectively removes all children from `this.itemLayer`, but `this.clusterLayer` is unaffected.

Similarly when adding data to `this.itemLayer`, that group creates new child layers, but MCG is unaffected.

Then when calling `this.clusterLayer.refreshClusters(this.itemLayer)`, none of the child layers of `this.itemLayer` are part of `this.clusterLayer`, so it ends up with unexpected effect (maybe just doing nothing special).

If you want to change the clustered layers, make sure to remove them from MCG (e.g. simply do `this.clusterLayer.clearLayers()`), then add back the new layers into it. You could also remove the current MCG and build a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out later this week.

Comment: `this.itemLayer.clearLayers()
this.itemLayer.addData(this.props.items)
this.clusterLayer.clearLayers()
this.clusterLayer.addLayer(this.itemLayer)
`
Seems to work. Does it look correct to you @ghybs