# Marker cluster clearLayers method does not remove the layers from the map

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using `"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.0"` into an Angular app.
The marker cluster is created as follow:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterGroup({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    disableClusteringAtZoom: this.maxZoom,
});
```

then is added to the map `this.map.addLayer(this.markerCluster);`.
Adding markers to the marker cluster works like a charm (`this.markerCluster.addLayers(this.markerLayers);`) but the problem appears when I'm trying to delete them because `this.markerCluster.clearLayers();` does not remove the layers from the map and I have to do it manually:

```
this.markerLayers.forEach((x) => {
    this.map.removeLayer(x);
});
```

Isn't expected from `clearLayers` method to remove the layers also from the map?

Comment: It should be indeed. Have you tried with a previous version of the plugin? Can you provide a reproduction example of your issue, for example using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz?

Comment: It will take a couple of hours to extract it. But I think I found something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862370/refresh-marker-clusters-after-geojson-layer-has-changed and here
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/647#issuecomment-200188598 . It's like the marker cluster group is decoupled from the map.